# Como hacer una consulta de tres tablas relacionadas en SQL?

Tags: sql

Como hacer una consulta de tres tablas relacionadas, he intentado con esto

```
SELECT B.titulo, b.id, u.id
FROM perfil_pregunta ub
INNER JOIN respuesta_seleccion u
ON  b.respuesta_seleccion_id = u.id
INNER JOIN respuesta b
ON ub.id = b.respuesta_seleccion_id
```

pero me lanza error,tambien intente con este otro

```
SELECT B.titulo, b.id, u.id, b.respuesta_seleccion_id
FROM perfil_pregunta ub
INNER JOIN respuesta_seleccion u
ON ub.respuesta_seleccion_id = u.id
INNER JOIN respuesta b
ON ub.id = b.respuesta_seleccion_id
```

Pero no me devuelve todos los datos relacionados.

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Comment: Deseo relacionar sacar la relacion entre perfil_pregunta respuesta_seleccion y respuesta

Comment: ¿Qué error te envía?

Comment: No podemos saber cual es tu problema a menos que digas el error que recibis, o en el caso que recibas datos errones, cuales son y cuales querias recibir. Y podrias aclara que base de datos es?

Answer (score 0):

En el último join cambia ub por u tal como te muestro en la consulta.

```
SELECT B.titulo, b.id, u.id
FROM perfil_pregunta ub
INNER JOIN respuesta_seleccion u
ON  b.respuesta_seleccion_id = u.id
INNER JOIN respuesta b
ON u.id = b.respuesta_seleccion_id
```

Me parece que el error en tu consulta es que tratas de establecer una relación del id de la primera tabla con la tercera cuando tu relación debería ser del id de la segunda con la tercera tal como muestra tu gráfico